# Javascript setTimeout and .animate Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, timeout

I am trying to make the page scroll to an image at the bottom, and on the way to scrolling to the bottom, fade in some text. I don't want to fade the text in before the scrolling down, or after the scrolling down (which is what the current code results in). I want a timed event in the middle of an .animate event.

HTML loaded with bootstrap

```
<div id="scrollFixedFall">
    <center>
    <br><br>
    <font size="200px" color="white" id="text1">A web design demonstration</font>
    </center>
    </div>

    <div id="blueSky">
    </div>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

Javascript with jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("body").fadeIn(1000);

        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#text1").fadeIn(2000);
        },1000);

        $("html, body, #text1").animate({ scrollTop
```

Here's the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/pm27go6s/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you monkeyinsight, but I've found a different solution that might help others that find this question. I decided to switch out setTimeout() with delay(). It's given me less trouble and more control, and I can have one element in multiple animates.

I went from

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#text1").fadeIn(2000);
    },1000);
```

to

```
    $("#text1").delay( 1000 ).fadeIn(2000);
```

Here's the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/pm27go6s/5/

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching 2 animate to 1 element and one can't execute till other is finished, you should remove #text1 from `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 4000);`, hope this will work for you

http://jsfiddle.net/pm27go6s/4/